# Find kth min node in AVL tree

Tags: algorithm, min, avl-tree

I now have built a AVL tree, Here is  a function to find kth min node in AVL tree
(k started from 0)
Code:

```java
int kthMin(int k)
{
    int input=k+1;
    int count=0;
    return KthElement(root,count,input);
}

int KthElement( IAVLTreeNode * root, int count, int k)
{
    if( root)
    {
        KthElement(root->getLeft(), count,k);
        count ++;
        if( count == k)
            return root->getKey();
        KthElement(root->getRight(),count,k);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

It can find some of right nodes, but some may fail, anyone can help me debug this> 
THanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple algorithm for Kth smallest node in any tree in general:-

```java
count=0, found=false;

kthElement(Node p,int k) {

    if(p==NULL)
        return -1

    else {

        value = kthElement(p.left)             
        if(found)
            return value 

        count++
        if(count==k) {
            found = true
            return p.value
        }

        value = kthElement(p.right)
        return value
    }
}
```

**Note:-** Use of global variables is the key.

Answer (score 0):

From the root, after recursing left, `count` will be 1, regardless of how many nodes are on the left.

You need to change `count` in the recursive calls, so change `count` to be passed by reference (assuming this is C++).

```cpp
int KthElement( IAVLTreeNode * root, int &count, int k)
```

(I don't think any other code changes are required to get pass by reference to work here).

And beyond that you need to actually return the value generated in the recursive call, i.e. change:

```cpp
KthElement(root->getLeft(), count, k);
```

to:

```cpp
int val = KthElement(root->getLeft(), count, k);
if (val != 0)
   return val;
```

And similarly for `getRight`.

Note I used `0`, not `NULL`. `NULL` is typically used to refer to a null pointer, and it converts to a `0` `int` (the latter is preferred when using `int`).

This of course assumes that `0` isn't a valid node in your tree (otherwise your code won't work). If it is, you'll need to find another value to use, or a pointer to the node instead (in which case you can use `NULL` to indicate not found).

Comment: Hi Duke, thanks for your advice, I found the bug now, it seems that after some recursive call, the final return value always be the last line "return NULL". I now used a private variable "int kth" under the line if( count == k) kth=root->getKey(); then return kth in the first Kthmin function. Then problem solved.